# Sending a single email from a view

Tags: views, rules, webforms, emails

I have a view where each page is a contract.  My client wants a button on the page that says "Send me more information." The button will send two emails, one to the customer saying "We'll get back to you" and one to my client.  My client's email needs to contain several fields from the view. (User email and name and node title at least.)

I've looked at various ways to do this, and none are quite right.

- Views Send opens a message form.  I want the customer to do nothing more than click the button.
- Webform would be good but I don't know how to pass the data from the view into a hidden field on the form.
- Rules would work but I can't figure out what the event would be to trigger sending the emails.

I am an experienced site builder but really know zip about PHP, so I can't make a custom module.

Does anyone have any good ideas for what seems like a simple thing to do? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

First thought that comes to mind:

I presume you have your view setup with an argument to create the different pages. Something like `/productinformation/%`

You could setup a second views display with an extended URL like `/productinformation/%/senddetails`

You can now make a couple of rules, whenever someone accesses `/productinformation/%/senddetails` you send the emails and redirect them back to `/productinformation/%`

When you send emails using rules you have access to tokens. This should give you access to things like the User Email or Page title. This is the part I'm not sure about, I don't know if you can get all the information you require through these tokens. Good luck!